# mongodb update an existing field without overwritting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```json
{
   questions: {
      q1: "",
   }
}
```

result after updating:

```json
{
   questions: {
      q1: "",
      q2: ""
   }
}
```

I want to add `q2` inside questions, without overwritting what's already inside it (`q1`).

One solution I found is to get the whole document, and modify it on my backend, and send the whole document to replace the current one. But it seems really in-effiecient as I have other fields in the document as well.

Is there a query that does it more efficiently? I looked at the `mongodb` docs, didn't seem to find a `query` that does it.

Comment: You can use `$set: { "questions.q2": "" }` like look at [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fWSjdH2T8BM)

Comment: @turivishal it seems to work in the playground, when I query it from my backend to the database, it says  `Cannot create field 'q2' in element {questions: "q1"}`

Comment: this will work when questions field type is object or questions field not exists in documents that you are updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As turivishal said, you can use `$set` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vLoxvUhNQNf)

But you also can use `$addFields` in this way:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "questions.q1": "q1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "questions.q2": "q2"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uLm5jpfUQjq)

Also, reading your comment where you say `Cannot create field 'q2' in element {questions: "q1"}`. It seems your original schema is not the same you have into your DB.

Your schema says that `questions` is an object with field `q1`. But your error says that `questions` is the field and `q1` the value.

Comment: @ J.F.
sorry, I had a problem with my query part, I was trying to do :


` db.updateOne(
{"questions.q2":{
$exists:true
}},
{$set:{
  "questions.q2":""
}}
). ` 
  

Just wondering, the way you could send a link to create mongo playground example, is that done in vsCode?

Comment: Just go to web (https://mongoplayground.net), create your query and click 'share' to get the link. Is not vsCode, is a Mongo web.